# How to amplify low voltage back up to supply level

Tags: not-gate, voltage-amplification

I have a voltage supply that provides 6 V. The voltage gets run through a complex series of transistors, and the output is around 1.5 V. This is too low for the rest of my circuit to work with. In order to raise the voltage, I have the following circuit consisting of two NOT gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM7qea.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, when the input is off, electricity is being wasted running through the 100 Ω resistor. Is there a way to create this sort of circuit without this waste? I tried connecting the input to the base of a transistor with the collector connected to + but that didn't work.

Comment: I assume your output node has to drive some sort of significant load, otherwise you wouldn't have chosen 100 Ohms. Just how much current does it have to supply?

Comment: A comparator with push/pull output (or a opamp configured as comparator) ? Depending on how much output current is required...

Comment: What is the output and how is it connected? A "push pull" output stage would do what you want but you may be able to get away with a much simpler "low side switch". (Searching these will give you more information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its depends on what you need for the output drive current. If you need a signal that goes high when the input is high, you might be better off using a PNP at the output.

Remove Q2 and R2. Connect a PNP: emitter = 6V; base = collector of Q1 via 10 kΩ ; collector = output. Add a pull-down resistor if needed at the output.

You probably need a resistor at the input also -- else the circuit may overload the circuit that is driving it. 10 kΩ would work there too.